# C# recursion, when one class contains object of the other

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm stuck with the following problem - I have two classes:

```
public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public Component()
    {
        Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }

}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }

}
```

As You can see, `Ingredient` class containt object of `Component` type, and inside the `Component` there is a `List` of `Ingredients`. 
My question is - how to create a function that can check every `Component` (that comes from database), go inside the `List`, check it, and go deeper if it is not empty, but if it is, go back and check other element of the `List`.

I'm sorry if my explanation is bad.

Comment: You can start with `void Function(Component c){...` Not really sure what you have problem with as there is no code in the post that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still vague, as we don't know what you want the results to be if any, but depending on what you are trying to do, here's a skeleton of what you may need.

```
public void DeepDive(Component component) {
var currentIngredients = component.Ingredients;
//This only works because the List is already initialized in the Component constructor.
if(currentIngredients.Any())
    foreach(Ingredient ingredient in currentIngredients) {
        //do stuff
        if(ingredient.Component != null)
            DeepDive(ingredient.Component);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had completely no inspiration for this. That works well for me ! Easy and simple. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: no problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will return a list of all of the components found by iterating through the ingredients.  It will check that it does not include a component more than once by reference.  If you are duplicating components in your code, meaning more than one instance for the same component, then you will need an equality check in place of the foundcomponents.Contains.

```
function IList<Component> GetAllComponents(Component startingComponent) {
    IList<Component> foundcomponents = new List<Component>();
    foundcomponents.Add(startingComponent);
    int searchindex = 0;
    while(searchindex<foundcomponents.Count) {
        Component c = foundcomponents[searchindex];
        if(c.Ingredients!=null) {
            foreach(Ingredient i in c.Ingredients) {
                if(i.Component!=null && foundcomponents.Contains(i.Component)) {
                    foundcomponents.Add(i.Component);
                }
            }
        }
        searchindex++;
    }
    return foundcomponents;
}
```